# When using an assembly of vector registers(NEON) in ARMv8 environment, double-precision does not apply

Tags: assembly, floating-point, precision, neon, armv8

I am coding using double data type in ARMv8 environment. When the optimization option -O3 is given, the value implemented in C language is different from that of using ARMv8 instruction in Assembly(NEON). When FMUL and FADD are used alone, the values are the same, but when FMUL + FADD are used at the same time, the result value is different from that of C language. We want to solve this problem.

here assembly file

```
.data

.text
.global Asm_Operation_Test

Asm_Operation_Test:

MOV x3,#0

Operation_Loop:

LD1 {v0.2d-v3.2d},[x0],#64
LD1 {v4.2d-v7.2d},[x1],#64

FMUL v0.2d,v0.2d,v4.2d
FADD v0.2d,v0.2d,v4.2d

FMUL v1.2d,v1.2d,v5.2d
FADD v1.2d,v1.2d,v5.2d

FMUL v2.2d,v2.2d,v6.2d
FADD v2.2d,v2.2d,v6.2d

FMUL v3.2d,v3.2d,v7.2d
FADD v3.2d,v3.2d,v7.2d

ST1 {v0.2d-v3.2d},[x2],#64
ADD x3,x3,#1
CMP x3,#32
BNE Operation_Loop

ret
```

here C file

```
typedef struct {double v;} fpr;

C_Operation Test(fpr*a, fpr*b, fpr*c){
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
   {
      c[i].v = a[i].v * b[i].v + b[i].v;
    }
}
```

Assembly functions and C functions perform the same operation as each other. The input data is a double type, and an array of 256 random numbers (double) is entered. If the gcc -O0 option is added, the results of the two functions are exactly the same. However, when gcc-O3 is performed, the result value of the two functions is not exactly the same, and only 12 decimal are the same as single-precision. We want to know the reason for this.

our compare function is simple.
if( (double) a[i].v != (double)b[i].v)) printf("Error\n")

Comment: Can you add more details regarding the issue?  For example, can you show the lines of C code, assembly lines, and the values mentioned in the question as well as identifying what compiler is used?

Comment: Sonds like FMA instructions are used.  Check the documentation supplied by your compiler vendor.  There's likely an option to enforce correct rounding of all subexpressions.

Comment: I've attached code and additional explanations. Also we use Jetson Xavier (ARMv8.2), we use gcc 7.5.0. The we confirmed that ARMv8 floating point-instruction set supports support Double-Precision.

Comment: The C standard does not require a direct correspondence between C operators and IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic operations, nor does it require the nominal precision be used in evaluate floating-point expressions. In C, `a*b + c` may be compiled as either a multiplication of `a` and `b` (which rounds to the nearest value representable in the type) followed by an add of `c` (which also rounds) or fused multiply-add (which computes the single result a•b+c as if there were only one rounding at the end). Further, `float` expressions may be computed with the `double` type and so on.

Comment: So, if you want to match your assembly to the C code for some reason, you could compile the C code with a request to the compiler to show the generated assembly (`-S` in GCC and Clang) and then rewrite your assembly to match. But generally there is little reason to do that. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Do you really need the assembly to exact match the C? Why? Or is your concern that the mismatch indicates some error in the computation?

Comment: What do “FMUL and FADD are used alone” and “FMUL + FADD are used at the same time” mean? FMUL and FADD are separate instructions; they are always executed separately. To illustrate what you mean, show two pieces of assembly, one that uses them “alone” and one that uses them “at the same time”.

Comment: This does not make any sense: “our compare function is simple. if( (double) a[i].v != (double)b[i].v)) printf("Error\n")” because the code you show writes its results to `c`, not to `a` or `b`. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Include complete code that can be executed, with input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: When only the FMUL instruction is used in the assembly function and only the multiplication operation is performed in the C function, the values are exactly the same, but when FMUL FADD is used sequentially and the C function is used sequentially too, the values are not the same (gcc -O3) . Attach the executable code. (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e_MppPCPRaBl1hpPXWJVYs4OtVfb68Dn?usp=sharing)

Our purpose is an implementation for FFT operations in the ARM environment. In other words, the goal is to make the result of the FFT operation perfectly equal.

Comment: Re “the goal is to make the result of the FFT operation perfectly equal”: Why? What is wrong with slightly different results? The C code does not produce the **exact** FFT results, because it has numerous roundings in the computations. Floating-point arithmetic is generally different from real-number arithmetic. So why make the assembly result exactly reproduce a non-exact result? What is wrong with having a result that is different but still accurate?

Comment: Our final goal is to solve the NTRU equation. In case of FFT Reference implementation in C language using double type, NTRU equation is perfectly solved. However, our FFT asm implementation does not solve the NTRU equation and runs into an infinite loop. What we could do was check each other's values, and in the end we decided there was an error with the floating point number. When comparing the result of the C language FFT function with the result of our Asm FFT function, the integer part of type double and 12 decimal places match perfectly, but the rest after 12 decimal places do not match.

Comment: It is unlikely that differences between a correctly implemented C FFT and a correctly implemented but different assembly FFT could result in an NTRU implementation failing for one but not the other. The reason for that is that a C implementation necessarily has floating-point rounding errors just as the assembly implementation does. So any algorithm that uses FFT results, whether it is an NTRU implementation or something else, must have some tolerance for the error in the FFT results…

Comment: … That leaves four possibilities. One, the NTRU implementation accepts FFT results with some error, but it is quirky about the errors it accepts, and the C implementation just happens to satisfy them in the cases you have tested. Two, the NTRU implementation accepts FFT results with some error, and the assembly implementation is a little less accurate than the C implementation and is outside the NTRU’s tolerance. Three, there is an error in the assembly implementation. Four, something else is wrong in the integration of the assembly implementation with the NTRU implementation.

Comment: My sense of is the likelihood of those is in the reverse order: It is quite likely that something is wrong in how the assembly FFT is being used in the NTRU implementation, somewhat likely that there is an error in the assembly implementation you have not discovered yet, less likely that the NTRU requires an FFT accuracy that the assembly implementation is not quite satisfying, and least likely that it just happens to be okay with the specific errors the C implementation produces.

Comment: In any case, the solution for making the assembly implementation match the C implementation is obvious: Tell the compiler to generate assembly code, then edit your assembly code to match the compiler’s assembly code.

Comment: If you really want to nail down the differences, then instrument the NTRU code so you can find the first place where its computation using the C FFT results differs from its computation using the assembly FFT results. That would at least produce a [mre] you could share with Stack Overflow; you would be able to show two complete FFTs with input data and point to a specific difference in their results that matters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Instead of chasing floating-point numbers as your advised, I went through all the possibilities at the function level. We are optimizing a PQC(Post-Quantum Cryptography) algorithm called Falcon. In Reference Implementation of Falcon, we re-examined the NTRU equation and understand how our implementation differs from the C implementation. After debugging all the code, I discovered that solving the NTRU equation may not compute all the layers of the FFT. Thank you so much~ Bless you!

Answer (score 6):

You can see from [the compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/85zznhK8M) that GCC emits the `fmla` instruction to do the multiply and add simultaneously.  This is both faster and more accurate than doing `fmul/fadd` separately.  So to the extent that there is a discrepancy in output between the C function and your assembly function, one would expect it is your assembly function that gives the worse answer.  You should be able to confirm this, for instance, by doing a test which computes the result at quad precision (`long double` on ARM64) or with an arbitrary-precision math package.

I'm not sure why you would want to deliberately make the C function behave worse, but if you do, you can use the option `-ffp-contract=off` to disable the use of fused multiply-add.  [See on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nM7YK98rP).

As a side note, if you want the compiler to produce vectorized code like yours, you'll need to declare at least the pointer argument `c` as `restrict` (and of course ensure that the `c` array never overlaps `a` or `b`).  Otherwise GCC will test for aliasing and fall back to a non-vectorized version if needed, [see on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GWcdGs7Ko).

You'll probably also want to upgrade your compiler.  The links above are with GCC 11.1, the code generated by GCC 7.3 is [still vectorized but much more complicated](https://godbolt.org/z/ndeYGr7jc).